# Can I create a Google Calendar event that repeats at every 1st, 3rd and 5th Friday in the month?

Tags: google-calendar

Is it possible to create an event that repeats at every 1st, 3rd and 5th Friday in the month in Google calendar?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Although Google Calendar doesn't allow you to create or modify arbitrary recurrence rules, the iCalendar specification which it uses and understands is *quite* robust in this regard.

Create an ICS file with a custom recurrence rule (RRULE).  For example, for an all-day event on the first, third, and fifth Fridays of every month, starting 2 March 2012:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120302
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20120302
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1FR,3FR,5FR
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Event on the first, third, and fifth Fridays.
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**To import the ICS file (updated June 2018):** Click the gear icon and select "Settings", then choose "Import & export" from the menu. ([Here's a direct link as of June 2018](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings/export).)  Under "Import", select your ICS file and upload it to the desired calendar.

For this example, Google Calendar parses the RRULE correctly and even describes the recurrence as "Monthly on Friday of weeks 1, 3, 5 of the month":

[image: Google Calendar event form showing recurrence rule reading "Monthly on Friday of weeks 1, 3, 5 of the month"]

Of course, you won't be able to tweak the custom recurrence rule from within Google Calendar, unless you want to replace the recurrence rule entirely with one of the standard options.  Otherwise, you'll have to delete the event, tweak your ICS file, and reimport.  You should still be able to make other changes to the event within Google Calendar, such as renaming, moving to another calendar, etc.

If this helps, you may wish to read more about the flexibility offered by [custom recurrence rules in the iCalendar specification](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html).

Comment: Something about this didn't work when importing, but the error message wasn't at all useful. I was able to export my existing calendar, leave all the junk in there between VCALENDAR and VEVENT, then strip out all but one event and modify that to make it work. The dates look a little different and there's no INTERVAL, but I don't know exactly what was causing it to fail

Comment: I updated the DTEND value (so that DTEND is in the future), created a new calendar and tried to import this into the newly created calendar. All I get, However, is `Processed one event. Successfully imported 0 events.` I also tried to add 'VERSION:2.0' and 'PRODID:[my-last-name]'. Each change gave the same result.

Comment: http://www.amilkhanzada.com/2013/06/google-calendar-repeating-events-on.html <-- this link shows how to do it on the web; ti syncs to the phone just fine

Comment: Worked well for me. Example with time:

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20170118T121500
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20170118T134500
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1WE,3WE,5WE
DESCRIPTION:Toastmasters
LOCATION:Bridge St
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Toastmasters Standards Australia
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Comment: See my 2018 updated solution below.

Comment: This does not work for me in May 2021. Says imported 0 of 1 events.

Answer (score 10):

The only practical way to achieve this is to create three separate events, one that repeats the 1st Friday, one that repeats on the 3rd Friday, and one on the 5th Friday (although not every month is going to have a 5th Friday).

[image: recurring appt monthly on third friday]

***Update***: Another method occurs to me: You would need to create 12 separate recurring appointments, one for each month, that starts on the first Friday of the month, repeats every two weeks, and ends on the last day of the month. Then you will hit, for that month, the first, third and, if it exists, fifth Friday.

Comment: That leaves the question about how you create an event that repeats on every 5th friday. When I click on repeat every month I get: repeats every last friday.

Comment: @Al Everest, this is not really possible in Google Calendar, you can't choose 1st, 3rd, or 5th if you are selecting the Monthly repeats..!! When you're selecting monthly repeats you can only choose which day of the month, not of the week!

Comment: @Lipis: Oh really? What about the screen shot I've added? It clearly shows that you can choose to repeat on the third Friday of every month.

Comment: @Al Everett.. oups...! :) Missed that.. that's why we are here after all.. good to know!

Comment: It's possible to create something that repeats every third Friday. If you click on day of the week you however don't get repeats every 5th Friday.

Comment: Because not every month has a fifth Friday. I suggest it's probably pretty rare for someone to schedule something for that fifth Xday every month but only if the fifth one exists. Everyone else would be looking to schedule that last Xday. You have a very unusual requirement. My second suggestion sort of meets that need. Beyond that, do what Traveling Tech Guy suggests and write your own app that utilizes the Calendar API.

Comment: If you start to shedule every 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4st Friday than you don't want to leave the 5st Friday empty but shedule something at those days as well. I don't think that this desire is that unique.

Comment: Yes, but then it's simple to schedule every Friday.

Comment: It actually is possible to schedule on every 5th Friday with a "hack". See my answer below or this blog post: http://www.amilkhanzada.com/2013/06/google-calendar-repeating-events-on.html

Answer (score 1):

Some of the methods addressed here no longer work, though the accepted answer works fine.

Heres another way - create an event that repeats on every xth weekday for each repetition you need.

Here's the process: create an event on the correct weekday, then go to repetition -> monthly -> repeat on every xth weekday. You can duplicate the event to make creation of the other events faster.

For repeating every 5th weekday, you'll need to use an application that takes advantage of the Google calendar API that allows repetition every fifth Sunday. I use the well-made Business Calendar 2 for this purpose, but there are others that work as well.

See the attached photo for evidence that Google API supports this behavior.

[image: Google Calendar 5th weekday repetition example]

Comment: As of June 2018, Google Calendar still supports importing ICS files as suggested in my accepted answer, though things have moved around a bit, so I've updated it.  It could be argued that accomplishing this with several separate events is just as much of a "hack" as using a custom recurrence rule to keep it all together, but they're still both valid approaches.

Comment: My apologies, your method works fine - I was addressing another method that no longer works. That said, a solution for those allergic to code is nice to have. =)

Answer (score 1):

No other method worked at all for me except for the ICS file import.  My need was to specify what happened on a doctor's schedule on particular weekdays on the 5th week of any month.  If you have a need for 5th weeks, please feel free to use this changed ICS file as an example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20190430
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20190430
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=5TU
DESCRIPTION: 5th week test entry
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test-Event fifth Tuesdays
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to set this rule.

The closest thing that you can achieve is to set it to daily and repeating every 14 days starting from one Friday.

Comment: Very 14 days is something completely different as the event happens at certain days in reality.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with "you can't do it" answers regarding a web app, I try to find out whether it has a published API and use that. Lucky for you, Google Calendar has a [well documented API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/). So if you can phrase your needs in any programming language, you can do it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try Quick Add and type something like `8:30-10:30 Swimming every 5th sunday of every month`.

Comment: This is a possible solution, but only works for every 5th Sunday, you'd need to add to this answer to address the rest of the question, as it's not as simple as adding 1 Quick Event to cover all recurrences.

Answer (score 0):

If you select a 5th friday and manually type "My Event on every 5th friday of every month" in the description box, it will add them appropriately.  Of course you would substitute your title for "My event".

Comment: This seems like a great answer, but I can't replicate the behavior in 2018 calendar. Does this still work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

Make a "sample" month, creating one Event on the first Friday, one on the third Friday and one on the fifth Friday.
For each event check the box "repeating"
In the repeating window, check monthly and day of the month.

Your event will now show up for all these dates for as long as you wish.

Comment: That's what I suggested in [my answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/6873/354), which the OP didn't like much.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the first day of the series in Google Calendar and type 'My Event, fifth Sunday of every month, 12:30-3:00' in the "What:" field:

Here is a blog post with more details: http://www.amilkhanzada.com/2013/06/google-calendar-repeating-events-on.html

Answer (score -1):

If you select the third Friday of the month for the first occurrence and then select monthly it will figure out what you are doing and look just like your screenshot.