# Google Calendar recurring date: Saturday before third Sunday

Tags: google-calendar

I want to import a recurring date in Google calendar.

FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=3SU;BYMONTH=7 is the third Sunday in July

But I want Saturday before the third Sunday of July. And also the Sunday, Monday and Tuesday after the found Saturday.

Is there a solution?

Comment: I'm afraid Google Calendar isn't that sophisticated.

Comment: That said, [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/24182/354) shows how you might use the iCalendar spec to put in some rather exotic repeating patterns.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of searching and trying I found a solution:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130720
DTEND:20130723
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=7;BYDAY=SA;BYMONTHDAY=14,15,16,17,18,19,20
SUMMARY:My event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: If you'd made your new variant a question, I'd have added an answer, albeit very late.  In short though, you can use negative values in BYMONTHDAY to count back from the end of the month.