# Google Calendar to set every 1st and 15th day of the month 9:00am-9:05am

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way I can create a Google Calendar invite and set it every 1st and 15th day of the month for 1 year duration and 9:00am-9:05am Central Time?

Comment: Have you read [Can I create a Google Calendar event that repeats at every 1st, 3rd and 5th Friday in the month?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/6849/196152). Create and import an iCal file containing your event parameters.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way, at least not in the UI. Since it's also not common in other calendars (Outlook, Apple) I use, and they all share a common interchangeable format with only some product-specific additions, I think Google Calendar simply does not support it.

I would opt to create *two* repeating events, one for the first day of the month and one for the 15th.

Comment: _I think Google Calendar simply does not support it._ Google Calendar supports both iCal as well as csv.