# Next to the last Saturday repeating Google Calendar event

Tags: google-calendar

How do I create an event in Google Calendar that repeats on the next to the last Saturday in July?

@Tedinoz I created an ics file with the RRULE you mentioned. In Apple calendar, it added it on Jan 1, 2003. In Google Calendar it says "Imported 0 out of 0 events. Unable to process your iCal/CSV file."

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYSETPOS=4;BYDAY=-2SA;BYMONTH=7.
SUMMARY:Foo Bar
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230101
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:Next to the last Sat in Jul
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create a Google Calendar event that repeats at every 1st, 3rd and 5th Friday in the month?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-create-a-google-calendar-event-that-repeats-at-every-1st-3rd-and-5th-frid)

Comment: RRULE? Try this: FREQ=YEARLY;BYSETPOS=4;BYDAY=-2SA;BYMONTH=7. Or refer to [RRULE Tool](https://icalendar.org/rrule-tool.html)